# mysql: Count number of occurances of uppercase-letters in a string

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL-Database with a column `mystring varchar(255)`.

What I want to know is the occurences of standard latin uppercase letters ('A' to 'Z').

So for example "AbcDeF" countains 3 upperscase letters and "XYZZ" contains 4.

Basically I would like to calculate the value in the database, something in the form of:

```
SELECT count_characters(mystring, 'A', 'Z') FROM mytable;
```

Is it possible in MySQL?

Comment: Short answer: No, not really.  Suggestion: query the string from mySQL with your favorite language, then count the upper-cases characters in that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result can be returned from MySQL. It's not impossible, but it's downright ugly. To make this prettier, you need to hide the ugliness in a user defined function.

You can use the `REPLACE` function to do a case sensitive search, to replace a specific character with a zero length string. Repeat that for each specific character you want to count. Then get the character length of the resulting string, and subtract that from the character length of the original string. The difference is the number of characters that were replaced (which was the number of characters you wanted to count).

As an example, to get a count of the uppercase letters 'A' thru 'D' from a particular column, for each row in your table...

```
  SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(t.mycol) -
         CHAR_LENGTH(
            REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
              t.mycol
            ,'A','')
            ,'B','')
            ,'C','')
            ,'D','')
         ) AS count_characters
    FROM mytable t
```

It's ugly, but it will return the specified result.

NOTE: The `LENGTH` function would work for the latin characters 'A' thru 'Z', but we use the `CHAR_LENGTH` function in anticipation of handling multi-byte UTF encodings.